# How to remove folders and files from git?

Tags: git, gitignore, pull

I have some folders which was included in git commits in the past and now I would like to remove it from git.

So I have added the folder in .gitignore. But if I try to pull changes from server it throws me an error:

> Pull failed. Some untracked working tree files would be overwritten by Pull. Please move or remove them before you can Pull.

In .gitignore is the line

```
/storage
```

which should ignore everything what is in the storage directory. So why the pull has problem with file in storage/logs/20201455.log file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the storage directory is already checked in to your repository you need to remove it:

```
git rm -r storage
git commit -m "Removed storage"
```

BUT this will also remove the contents of your storage directory, so move it somewhere safe first.

```
mv storage storage_orig
git rm -r storage
git commit -m "Removed storage"
mv storage_orig storage
```

Comment: This is the best answer I ever get. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Adding on to what biomiker mentioned, you can also do this:

```
git rm -r --cached storage
```

This will only remove it from the repository and keep the files, keep in mind you will have to add ./storage to your .gitignore file to make sure it doesn't get added again to the repo.